# storing C struct as binary with SET in redis (hiredis)

Tags: c, redis, hiredis

I'm trying to save a binary blob of my structure as value in Redis (via hiredis) using SET. I set it with one execution of my program and try to retrieve it later in another run. For some reason, I'm not able to get the dynamically allocated string back.

Here's the simplified code fragments of what I'm doing. In the real implementation, my struct is more complex with strings, linked lists, sub structs.

```
typedef struct mytest {
    int myInt;
    char *myStr;
} mytest;

char *key = strdup("test_key");
int vsize = 0;

mytest t;
memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));
t.myInt = 100;
vsize += sizeof(t.myInt);
t.myStr = strdup("test_string");
vsize += strlen(t.myStr);

redisReply *reply = 0;

// set value
reply = redisCommand(context, "SET %b %b", key, (size_t) strlen(key), &t, (size_t) vsize);
if (!reply)
    return REDIS_ERR;
freeReplyObject(reply);

// get the value back
reply = redisCommand(context, "GET %b", key, (size_t) strlen(key));
struct mytest *retval = (struct mytest *) reply->str;

printf("GET %s: myInt = %d  myStr = %s", retval->myInt, retval->myStr);
```

I have following questions:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is SET/GET the correct way to store complex data structure or should I use something else in Redis? I want to access the structure as single entity and not as separate fields.
3. In case of member linked lists, how should they be stored?

I couldn't find any examples that address my use case, so any examples would help.

Comment: probablly because t only holds a pointer to a string, not a string itself, so it will be storing the pointer, and when you get the pointer back, the string is gone

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking along the same lines. So how can I make it work for a linked list member? Could I use the redis LIST separately and link it with the binary value here? I also explored redis hash (HMSET) but that seemed too cumbersome for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code do not work properly because of variable `to` contains string `myStr` as a pointer to string rather than string itself:

> reply = redisCommand(context, "SET %b %b", key, (size_t) strlen(key), **&t**, (size_t) vsize);

Try to work with this like that:

```
redisReply *reply = redisCommand(context, "SET %b %b", key, (size_t) strlen(key), t.myStr, t.myInt);
...
struct mytest;
memset(&mytest, 0, sizeof(mytest)); 

reply = redisCommand(context, "GET %b", key, (size_t) strlen(key));

mytest.myInt = strlen(reply->str);
mytest.myStr = strdup(reply->str);
freeReplyObject (reply);
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. So does that mean there's no way to store a struct containing pointers (strings, linked lists, etc) as binary? Do you have any suggestion on what I could do? Perhaps some other Redis data type or some sort of normalization before storing data?

Comment: Your structure contains pointer to string placed in other peace of memory. So if you want to write your structure as binary (any way as a string in redis) you should serialize them to proper data. You may write some kind of helper functions to serialize/deserialize your data to/from string. Keep in mind you cant just use redisReply->str without strdup because of this memory should be cleaned up with freeReplyObject.